# How do pass Context into multiple helper functions?

Tags: anchor, rust, rustc

sorry if this is a more rusty question.

As the title suggests, how can I pass the context struct into multiple helper functions?

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
impl<'info> BuyIn<'info> {
    pub fn handler(ctx: Context<BuyIn>) -> Result<()> {
        
        let tuple_vec = config!(
            "ZERO_LEVEL",
            "ZERO_MULTIPLIER",
            "ONE_LEVEL",
            "ONE_MULTIPLIER",
            "TWO_LEVEL",
            "TWO_MULTIPLIER",
            "THREE_LEVEL",
            "THREE_MULTIPLIER",
            "FOUR_LEVEL",
            "FOUR_MULTIPLIER"
        );
        msg!("{:#?}", tuple_vec);

        for x in tuple_vec {
            if x.0 == ctx.accounts.game.level {
                let (amount, fee_amount) = calculate_transfers(x.1);
                transfer_to_vault(&ctx, amount)?;
                transfer_to_fee_collector(&ctx, fee_amount)?;
                update_vault_state(&ctx, amount)?;
                update_game_state(ctx)?;
                break;

            }
        }

        Ok(())

    }
}
```

And here is what my helpers look like:

```
pub fn calculate_transfers(multiplier: f32) -> (u64, u64) {
    let amount = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL as f32 / multiplier;
    let fee_amount = (amount * FEE_PERCENTAGE) as u64;
    let amount = amount as u64 - fee_amount;
    (amount, fee_amount)
}

pub fn transfer_to_fee_collector(
    ctx: &Context<BuyIn>,
    amount: u64,
) -> Result<()> {

    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
        system_program::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.player.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.fee_collector.to_account_info(),
        });
    system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}

pub fn transfer_to_vault(
    ctx: &Context<BuyIn>,
    amount: u64,
) -> Result<()> {

    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
        system_program::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.player.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
        });
    system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}

pub fn update_game_state(ctx: Context<BuyIn>) -> Result<()> {
    let player = &mut ctx.accounts.player;
    let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;

    game.leaderboard.push(
        Rank {
            player: Some(player.key()),
            weight: None,
        }
    );

    Ok(())
}

pub fn update_vault_states(ctx: &Context<BuyIn>) -> Result<()> {
    let vault = &mut ctx.accounts.vault;                   // error here

    Ok(())
}
```

And the error I recieve is the following:
`rustc: cannot borrow 'ctx.accounts.vault' as mutable, as it is behind a '&' reference 'ctx' is a '&' reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed`

Ive tried getting all the accounts before the for loop and then passing those as parameters to the helper functions, also changed parameters to include &mut type, but this results in an error in other functions. Specifically transfer_to_vault. I get a trait bound not satisfied when getting/passing in the account_info() into the Transfer struct.

Thanks!

edit: Trying another method but I'm unsure if it will work. Im unable to clone ctx, but I can pass &ctx to the helper functions and clone the relative accounts there into new variables.

My confusion with this is if I clone into new variable, will the subsequent logic/operations not actually be reflected on chain?

```
        for x in tuple_vec {
            if x.0 == ctx.accounts.game.level {
                let (amount, fee_amount) = calculate_transfers(x.1);
                transfer_to_vault(&ctx, amount)?;
                transfer_to_fee_collector(&ctx, fee_amount)?;
                update_game_state(&ctx)?;
                update_vault_state(&ctx, amount)?;
            
                break;
            }
        }
```

And here are the new helpers:

```
pub fn calculate_transfers(multiplier: f32) -> (u64, u64) {
    let amount = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL as f32 / multiplier;
    let fee_amount = (amount * FEE_PERCENTAGE) as u64;
    let amount = amount as u64 - fee_amount;
    (amount, fee_amount)
}

pub fn transfer_to_vault(
    ctx: &Context<BuyIn>,
    amount: u64,
) -> Result<()> {

    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
        system_program::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.player.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
        });
    system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}

pub fn transfer_to_fee_collector(
    ctx: &Context<BuyIn>,
    amount: u64,
) -> Result<()> {

    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
        system_program::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.player.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.fee_collector.to_account_info(),
        });
    system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}


pub fn update_game_state(
    ctx: &Context<BuyIn>,
) -> Result<()> {
    let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game.clone();

    game.leaderboard.push(
        Rank { 
            player: Some(ctx.accounts.player.key()), 
            weight: None 
        }
    );

    Ok(())
}

pub fn update_vault_state(
    ctx: &Context<BuyIn>, 
    amount: u64
) -> Result<()> {
    let mut vault = ctx.accounts.vault.clone();
    vault.pot += amount;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: can you pass in ctx.clone() into your helper functions instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, Im unable to call clone() on ctx itself, nor can I the accounts field of ctx. However I can clone the accounts themselves! But Im unsure if my implementation will work.

I can pass in &ctx to my helpers, and then I can clone the relevant account and then do the operations. But thinking about this, if Im cloning the account into a new variable, will it not be writing to the relevant account that just got cloned? I edited in what we're discussing in the post ser

Comment: I edited in what we're discussing in the post ser

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code to use mutable references where needed rather than immutable references, which will then let you mutate.

So when you see:

```
pub fn update_game_state(ctx: Context<BuyIn>) -> Result<()> {
    let player = &mut ctx.accounts.player;
    let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;
```

You should do:

```
pub fn update_game_state(ctx: &mut Context<BuyIn>) -> Result<()> {
    let player = &mut ctx.accounts.player;
    let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
impl<'info> BuyIn<'info> {
    pub fn transfer_to_vault(&self, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
            system_program::Transfer {
                from: self.player.to_account_info(),
                to: self.vault.to_account_info(),
            });
        system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)
    }
}
```

and then in your instruction:

```
    ctx.accounts.transfer_to_vault(amount)?;
```